# Why is my iron disappearing in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, I'm in survival with a wooden pickaxe, and whenever I mine the iron ore I need, it keeps disappearing. Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Wooden Pickaxe?

Answer (score 7):

You mentioned you had a wooden pickaxe, this will not work for Iron Ore.

To quote the wiki:

> Iron ore will drop as an item if mined by a stone pickaxe or better. If mined by any other tool, it will drop nothing.

In order to get the Iron ore as an item drop you need to make a stone pickaxe. You can do this the same way you would make a wooden pickaxe just with stone along the top instead of wood.

Source: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Ore